# Problems transferring Json from javascript to PHP, why does one command work and the other does not

Tags: javascript, php, json

Can someone explain to me why one of the following code statements work and the other does not?

//This block doesn’t work

```
var str = JSON.stringify(myObj);
xmlhttp.open("POST","my.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
xmlhttp.send("obj=" + str + "&" + "name=" +document.getElementById("textBox1").value);
```

//This block does work

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","my.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
xmlhttp.send("obj=" + (JSON.stringify(myObj)) + "&" + "name=" +document.getElementById("textBox1").value);
```

In the working block the obj variable is set and ready when it gets to the php file.In the non working example the obj variable is not set when it arrives in the php file.

Comment: I don't think that can possibly be true if the **only** difference is that you stringify into a variable first. In any case, you really need to be URL-encoding the JSON: `"obj=" + encodeURIComponent(str) + ...`

Comment: It doesnt make any sense to me but it wouldnt work with way 1. If I try to use encodeURIComponent then the string only partially makes it to the php file. It is only 106k characters so length shouldnt be an issue I would think.

Comment: 106k characters is extremely big for a URL.

Comment: so your saying 106 char is too large. Is there another way I can transfer the string? Its just a JSON string and i dont really care what form it gets to my php file.

Comment: Wait wait - sorry, I was losing sight of what your code is doing. You should be fine; you're using a POST. I was thinking about parameters on a URL.  I really don't know how it could possibly make a difference between the first and second versions. Maybe check your browser "Network" console, and server logs, to see what's happening.